# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'newUser' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, registration

I’m new in Spring and trying to make a RegisterController for my Web portal. 
When I push button “Register” on my main page it shows this error:**"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'newUser' available as request".**
 I’ve already read a lot of posts on this topic but any of them were helpful.

**RegisterController.class**

```
import com.springapp.Entity.User;
import com.springapp.Service.UserService.UserService;
import com.springapp.mvc.RegisterForm;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register.do")
public class RegisterController {
//Log4j
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegisterController.class);

@Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

private void putNewUserForm(ModelMap model) {
    RegisterForm newUser = new RegisterForm();
    model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(ModelMap model) {
    putNewUserForm(model);
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegister(@ModelAttribute("newUser") 
       @Valid final RegisterForm  newUser, final BindingResult result, 
       Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.debug("result has errors!");
        return "register";
    }
    if (createUser(newUser, model)) {
        return "register";
    }
    return "welcome";
}

private boolean createUser(RegisterForm newUser, Model model) {
    User user = newUser.getUser();
    userService.insertUser(user);
    return false;
 }
}
```

**Register.jsp**

I tried to set commandName="newUser", but no difference.

```
<DIV class="registration_block">

           <sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="newUser" action="${app}/register.do">

                <sf:label path="login"><strong>Enter Login:</strong></sf:label>
                <sf:input path="login" type="text" size="20"/><br>
                <span class="error"><form:errors path="login"/></span>
                <br>

                .........

                <input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" value="Register"/>
            </sf:form>
```

**RegisterForm.class**

```
 import com.springapp.Entity.User;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
 import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
 import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
 import java.sql.Timestamp;


public class RegisterForm {
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(RegisterForm.class);

private Integer userId;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+$")
private String login;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z])+$")
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+$")

private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
private String passwordConfirm;

@NotEmpty
@Email
@Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\-+])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$")
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Email
private String emailConfirm;

private Timestamp regDate;

private String role;


public RegisterForm() {
}


public User getUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(userId);
    logger.trace("set user 'login'" + userId);
    user.setLogin(login);
    logger.trace("set user 'email'" + login);
    user.setEmail(email);
    logger.trace("set user 'firstName'" + email);
    user.setName(name);
    logger.trace("set user 'password'" + name);
    user.setPassword(password);
    logger.trace("set user 'password'" + password);
    user.setRegDate(regDate);
    logger.trace("set user regDate'" + regDate);
    return user;
}


public void setUser(User user) {
    logger.trace("Constructor " + user);
    this.userId = user.getUserId();
    logger.trace("Get 'id' " + getUserId());
    this.login = user.getLogin();
    logger.trace("Get 'login' " + user.getLogin());
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    logger.trace("Get 'password' " + user.getPassword());
    this.name = user.getName();
    logger.trace("get 'Name'" + name);
    this.email = user.getEmail();
    logger.trace("Get 'email' " + user.getEmail());
    this.regDate = user.getRegDate();
    logger.trace("Get 'regDate' " + user.getRegDate());
   }

 //Getters and Setters....

}
```

**MainController.class**

```
import com.springapp.Service.UserService.UserService;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class MainController {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MainController.class);

    @Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showIndexPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
    public String userWelcomePage() {
      return "welcome";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewall", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView listUsers(ModelAndView model) {    
        return model.addObject("members", userService.getAllUsers());
    }

    @RequestMapping("delete")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewall");
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return mav;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userEdit() {
         return "adminUserUpdate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView registerUser(ModelAndView model) {
        return model.addObject("register");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `BindingResult` is the model, however you also have the `Model` included in your signature and if I recall correctly this basically makes the model empty when rendering the page. Try removing that from your method signature.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've solved the problem. It was in RequestMapping.
Here is code, which works. Not perfectly yet, but it shows RegisterPage and allows to submit.

```
 import com.springapp.Entity.User;
 import com.springapp.Service.RoleService.RoleService;
 import com.springapp.Service.UserService.UserService;
 import com.springapp.mvc.RegisterForm;
 import com.springapp.mvc.UserValidator;
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult; 
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.validation.Valid;

 @Controller
 public class RegisterController {
 //Log4j
 private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegisterController.class);


 @Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
 @Autowired
 private UserService userService;  

 @Qualifier("roleServiceImpl")
 @Autowired
 private RoleService roleService;


 private void putNewUserForm(ModelAndView model) {
     RegisterForm newUser = new RegisterForm();
     model.addObject("newUser", newUser);
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String register(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("newUser", new RegisterForm());
     return "register";
 } 

 @RequestMapping(value = "/register.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String sayHello(RegisterForm newUser, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);   

    if (createUser(newUser, model)) {
        return "register";
    }
    return "welcome";
}

private boolean createUser(RegisterForm newUser, Model modelAndView) {
    User user = newUser.getUser();
    user.setRole(roleService.findByName(newUser.getRole()));
    userService.insertUser(user);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the ModelAttribute object before returning the page.

In your post method, there are 3 possiblities, and I since it says `'newUser'` is needed, it's quite possible that the same page `register` is returned, unless you have the ModelAttribute `'newUser'` in your `welcome`.

So, change it like this:

```
model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);
return "pageName";
```

Hope is works.

Comment: I've tried make whole controller with ModelAndView but result is the sane.

Comment: ROROROOROROR, could you advise what are another possiblities? Except using SimpleFormController?

Comment: Before modification, did you do a debug in the function `processRegister`? which page does it return?

Comment: Well, the problem is - those method is unavailable to debug because the page **register.jsp** isn't shown. I've added MainController.class above. Maybe it would help to find the problem.

Comment: In your  `registerUser()` method, `model.addObject("register");` , shouldn't this be `model.addObject("newUser",new RegisterForm());`, according to your jsp.